# How to change audio input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input-devices

I'm developing a webRTC app, and I want to give users the ability to change their inputs devices (microphones).

I've found the way to display the available devices using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`
but i'm not able to find how to actually select one of the devices?

How can i set the input device to use in javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by following the example here:
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/